# Xamarin Forms Maps - showing current location on iOS

Tags: c#, ios, google-maps, xamarin.forms

In Xamarin Forms, does the IsShowingUser property of Xamarin.Forms.Maps work for iOS?

I can get every aspect of my map to work on both Android and iOS, but the current location 'blue dot' does not show on iOS.

I'm setting this in shared code in the PCL project, just after successfully asking for permission to use location.

```
var status = await CrossPermissions.Current.CheckPermissionStatusAsync(Permission.Location);
            if (status != PermissionStatus.Granted)
            {
                var results = await CrossPermissions.Current.RequestPermissionsAsync(new[] { Permission.Location });
                status = results[Permission.Location];
            }

            if (status == PermissionStatus.Granted)
            {
                MyMap.IsShowingUser = true;
            }
```

thanks

Comment: I am also facing the same issue, did you get the answer. And also in my ios app the user current location button is not showing .but i am set the IsShowing=true

Comment: See the accepted answer, it did the job for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can get every aspect of my map to work on both Android and iOS, but the current location 'blue dot' does not show on iOS.

It is because the map doesn't locate the current user location at that time, you can use  [Xam.Plugin.Geolocator](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/GeolocatorPlugin) to get your current location, and move the map to it.

```
var locator = CrossGeolocator.Current;
var position = await locator.GetPositionAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
map.MoveToRegion(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(new Position(position.Latitude, position.Longitude),
                                                     Distance.FromMiles(1)));
```

Comment: Your code finds the position but the map doesn't move/zoom to the position. Is there a bug? @Cole Xia - MSFT

Comment: Im using xamarin forms maps (it should work according to documentation).